# AutoMapperMappingException when mapping different ViewModels to the same Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I'm using Automapper to map my view models to my domain Models. In my case i have two ViewModels which i need to be mapped to the same Model.

I create two profiles foreach view model then in `Mapper.Initialize` i add them both. Then in my controller, when i try to map my ViewModel to the Model so i can pass it to a service i got this error `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.`

My Code

```
public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new CompanyRegisterViewModelProfile()));
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new CompanyActivateViewModelProfile()));
        }
    }
```

Then in my controller:

```
CompanyEmployee CompanyEmployee = Mapper.Map<CompanyRegisterViewModel, CompanyEmployee>(model,);
```

Now if i removed the second profile `CompanyActivateViewModelProfile` i don't get any error and maping is done correctly. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As a suggestion, call Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid in Configure - then automapper throws errors on startup and not on first use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-initializing AutoMapper by calling `Mapper.Initialize` twice causing the first profile to be removed. Try this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new CompanyRegisterViewModelProfile());
        cfg.AddProfile(new CompanyActivateViewModelProfile());
    });
```

Comment: That's right. While i was searching for a solution, i noticed that I'm calling `Initialize` more than once, while i supposed to pass profile as list. That's what happen when working 10H without stopping

Comment: Also,  cfg.AddProfile<CompanyRegisterViewModelProfile>;